# Kalman Filter Tracking using given X,Y of the object in Opencv C++

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I'm new to Kalman tracking so I've got no idea how to start. I have program to detect faces, after a face has been detected, i want to send the center x.y of the face to the Kalman filter to draw a line showing the direction of movement. How do i start? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/06/17/simple-kalman-filter-for-tracking-using-opencv-2-2-w-code/).

Comment: I noticed it earlier but it looked complicated but after taking another look at it made sense thanks again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to understand the math for formulating the problem, the link offered by William is good place to experiment with the code. If you want to follow the math there are a few good places to check:

http://home.hit.no/~hansha/documents/control/theory/kalmanfilter.pdf

http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~rmf25/papers/Understanding%20the%20Basis%20of%20the%20Kalman%20Filter.pdf

http://old.shahed.ac.ir/references/kalman_filter_notes.pdf

and ofcourse

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter

has some excellent references to go through. Also...

Check out the Udacity course:

https://www.udacity.com/course/cs373

This has a section on Kalman filters programming using python.